# Pasar un Object dinámico de un Fragment a otro

Tags: android, object, retrofit

Buenas, estoy intentando pasar un Object que recibo desde un API de un Fragment a otro, este Object puede tener "N" cantidad de "key" = "values".
He intentado pasarlo por medio de un Bundle, pero hay que crear una clase que  Serializable o Parcelable, a lo cual no me funciona porque a la hora de crear los sets y los gets, no se cuantos valores van a venir desde el API.

```
            @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            ServerResponse resp = response.body();


            if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {

                Lo que obtengo del response lo paso a un objecto
                Object obj= resp.getResponse();
                //En esta parte intente con bundle pero no funciono
                goToContact();
            }
        }
```

Cualquier ayuda la apreciaría mucho!

Comment: ¿Y porqué no simplemente pasas un HashMap o similar?

Comment: ¿Y como?, ¿Parseo el obj a HashMap? @SJuan76

Answer (score 0):

Al final encontre sobre como pasar res.getResponse de una forma que me funciono, lo que hice fue pasar el **res.getResponse** a un string de la siguiente forma:

`String contactString = resp.getResponse().toString();`

Luego por medio de un **Bundle** puse el string de la siguiente forma:

`Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putString("contact", contactString);`

Posteriormente para pasarlo al fragment deseado hice una funcion la cual le va a pasar por parámetro un Bundle el cual se va a mandar al otro fragment por medio de un setArguments:

`private void goToContact(Bundle bundle){
        Fragment login = new TestFragment();
        login.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,login);
        ft.commit();
    }`

Luego llamo dicha función en donde se encuentra el Bundle del contacto:

`goToContact(args);`

Y finalmente en el fragment  llamado **TestFragment** en la funcion onCreateView para ver si todo funcionaba bien, para obtener el Bundle **"contact"**, lo llame de esta forma:

`String newContact = this.getArguments().getString("contact");`